# How to remove all dupes from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
// This is a large array of objects, e.g.:
let totalArray = [
    {"id":"rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4","fields":
    {"user_id":170180717,"user_name":"abcdefg","event_id":516575,
    }]

let uniqueArray = [];

let dupeArray = [];

let itemIndex = 0

totalArray.forEach(x => {
  if(!uniqueArray.some(y => JSON.stringify(y.fields.user_id) === JSON.stringify(x.fields.user_id))){
    uniqueArray.push(x)
  } else(dupeArray.push(x))
})

node.warn(totalArray);
node.warn(uniqueArray);
node.warn(dupeArray);

return msg;
```

I'm successfully deduping the array to produce only unique values. Problem is, I need to remove both duplicates, e.g.: if there are 2 objects with the same user_id key, I want to remove both of the objects from the array, not just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to iterate over the array and put the current object being iterated over at a `user_id` property on the object. If the property already exists there, reassign it to `null` instead. At the end, take the values of the object and remove the null values:

```js
const totalArray = [{
  "id": "rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
  "fields": {
    "user_id": 170180717,
    "user_name": "abcdefg",
    "event_id": 516575,
  }
}, {
  "id": "rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
  "fields": {
    "user_id": 170180717,
    "user_name": "abcdefg",
    "event_id": 516575,
  }
}, {
  "id": "unique",
  "fields": {
    "user_id": 1234,
    "user_name": "abcdefg",
    "event_id": 516575,
  }
}];
const uniques = {};
for (const item of totalArray) {
  const prop = item.fields.user_id;
  uniques[prop] = uniques.hasOwnProperty(prop)
    ? null
    : item;
}
const output = Object.values(uniques).filter(Boolean);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: is there meant to be a whitespace between "?" and "null"? I'm getting the error: "bad line breaking before '?'."

Comment: It's not necessary, but most will find it more readable when operators are separated from their operands by at least a space. `?null` looks really weird IMO. If you have a linting rule that forbids it, feel free to fix it according to the standards of your project

Comment: @CertainPerformance why is `const uniques = {}` set to an empty object?

Comment: @GPP The object is used as a mechanism to check how many times a particular `user_id` has been encountered so far. It starts out empty because no elements have been iterated over at the very beginning of the script.

Comment: `uniques[prop] = uniques.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? null : item` could also be written as `uniques[prop] = !uniques.hasOwnProperty(prop) && item` depending on preferred programming style.

Comment: I need the dupe to work exactly as you showed me, but the issue is is that my array has objects where the key value pair of user_id is at different paths. For some objects, it is at item.fields.user_id and for others it is at item.user_id (those are the only 2 paths). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @IgorLenterman Alternate between them? `const prop = item.user_id || item.fields.user_id`

Answer (score 1):

You could first group the objects based on `user_id`. Then partition them based on group size (if a group only contains a single record it is unique). Then flatten the groups so it'll end up as a normal array of records and not an array of groups of records.

```js
function groupBy(iterable, fn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = fn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}

function partition(iterable, fn) {
  const truthy = [], falsy = [];
  for (const item of iterable) {
    (fn(item) ? truthy : falsy).push(item);
  }
  return [truthy, falsy];
}

const totalArray = [{
  "id": "rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
  "fields": {
    "user_id": 170180717,
    "user_name": "abcdefg",
    "event_id": 516575,
  }
}, {
  "id": "rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
  "fields": {
    "user_id": 170180717,
    "user_name": "abcdefg",
    "event_id": 516575,
  }
}, {
  "id": "unique",
  "fields": {
    "user_id": 1234,
    "user_name": "abcdefg",
    "event_id": 516575,
  }
}];

const [uniqueArray, dupeArray] =
  partition(
    groupBy(totalArray, record => record.fields.user_id).values(),
    group => group.length == 1
  )
  .map(groups => groups.flat(1));

console.log("uniqueArray =", uniqueArray);
console.log("dupeArray =", dupeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` && `Array.some` like this:

```js
let totalArray = [
    {
      id: "rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
      fields:
      { 
        "user_id":170180717,
        "user_name":"abcdefg",
        "event_id":516575,
      }
    },
    {
      id:"rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
      fields:
      { 
        "user_id":170180717,
        "user_name":"abcdefg",
        "event_id":516575,
      }
    },
    {
      id:"rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
      fields:
      { 
        "user_id":1470107417,
        "user_name":"abcdefg",
        "event_id":516575,
      }
    },
    {
      id:"rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
      fields:
      { 
        "user_id":1470107417,
        "user_name":"abcdefg",
        "event_id":516575,
      }
    },
    {
      id:"rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4",
      fields:
      { 
        "user_id":14701073417,
        "user_name":"abcdefg",
        "event_id":516575,
      }
    }
];

let removeDups = totalArray.reduce((result,item,index,original)=>{
  if (original.some((o,i)=>o.fields.user_id===item.fields.user_id && i!==index)) return result;
  result.push(item); 
  return result;
},[])

console.log(removeDups);
```

Comment: Also you can check your result array not contains current item and it is more performant.