# How to remove dupe objects from an array with a key value at two different paths?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
// This is a large array of objects, with two different styles of object e.g.:
let totalArray = [

    {"id":"rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4","fields":
    {"user_id":170180717,"user_name":"testuser1","event_id":516575,
    }},

    {"user_id":170180717,"user_name":"testuser1","event_id":516575,
    },

    {"id":"rec014777","fields":
    {"user_id":12345,"user_name":"testuser2","event_id":03030,
    }},

    {"user_id":12345,"user_name":"testuser2","event_id":03030,
    },

    {"id":"rec01dXBXT4ZtHL4","fields":
    {"user_id":090909,"user_name":"testuser3","event_id":94949,
    }},

    {"user_id":48563,"user_name":"testuser4","event_id":33222,
    }];


const uniqueValues = {};
for (const item of totalArray) {
  const prop = item.fields.user_id;
  uniqueValues[prop] = uniqueValues.hasOwnProperty(prop)
    ? null
    : item;
}

msg.uniques = Object.values(uniques).filter(Boolean);

return msg;
```

The code above works to remove all duplicates (leaving only unique values which **didn't** have a pair). I need the dupe to work this way, but the issue is is that my array has objects where the key value pair of user_id is at different paths. In the example above, you will see that there is one path of item.fields.user_id and another of item.user_id. Right now my code works for an array objects with the item.fields.user_id, but I need it to work for the concat array of both object types. How can I solve this?

This is a follow up on help I received from @CertainPerformance here: [How to remove all dupes from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027139/how-to-remove-all-dupes-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are these the only two paths that are possible, or can the keys be arbitrarily named and nested `n` levels deep?

Comment: thanks so much! been learning a lot from this community already and am excited to pay it forward where I can.

Comment: now you took the code of an answer from your last question. why not ask a complete question with **your code** and get answers instead of using an incremental approach by using answer from older question for newer questions.

Comment: these are the two paths that the user_id value of the objects within the array can be accessed - does that answer your q? @ggorlen

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry I didn't know that was bad form - I'm working with a complex system so the help I got in my last q broke things elsewhere, and I'm a newb so struggling to fix. Apologies!

Comment: It's better to ask a new question rather than edit an already-answered question if the specification changed, but it's good to cite where the code in this question [came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027139/how-to-remove-all-dupes-from-an-array-of-objects).

Comment: please add a valid `totalArray`.

Comment: edited the question to include the information about the previous question and answer. Thanks for your guys' clarification on best pracitices here. I want to be a good community member! 
@NinaScholz Editing the question now with a complete totalArray of 6 objects.

Comment: @NinaScholz new array should leave the testuser3 and testuser 4 objects after deduping

Comment: the above data set is still not valid.

Comment: @NinaScholz forgive my syntax, just corrected!

Answer (score 0):

You could get either `item.user_id` or `item.fields.user_id` with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR).

```
const prop = item.user_id || item.fields.user_id;
```

```js
let totalArray = [{ id: "rec01dTDP9T4ZtHL4", fields: { user_id: 170180717, user_name: "testuser1", event_id: 516575 } }, { user_id: 170180717, user_name: "testuser1", event_id: 516575 }, { id: "rec014777", fields: { user_id: 12345, user_name: "testuser2", event_id: 3030 } }, { user_id: 12345, user_name: "testuser2", event_id: 3030 }, { id: "rec01dXBXT4ZtHL4", fields: { user_id: 90909, user_name: "testuser3", event_id: 94949 } }, { user_id: 48563, user_name: "testuser4", event_id: 33222 }];
const uniqueValues = {};

for (const item of totalArray) {
    const prop = item.user_id || item.fields.user_id;
    uniqueValues[prop] = uniqueValues.hasOwnProperty(prop) ?
        null :
        item;
}

console.log(Object.values(uniqueValues ).filter(Boolean));
```